# Should we tag with [karnaugh-map] instead of [k-map]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

We currently have [k-map](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-map) for questions about Karnaugh maps.  Is this the best possible tag name?  Would [karnaugh-map](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karnaugh-map) be a better choice?

For that matter, would a more general tag like [logic-synthesis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-synthesis) be more appropriate than either of those? I don't see a compelling reason to have a tag that covers Karnaugh maps but not, e.g., Quine-McCluskey or other methods for achieving the same goal.  Any opinions?

Comment: [tag:karnaugh-map] is explicit, so it looks much better to me.

Comment: I don't know the term "logic synthesis" so I can not comment on it's potential as a tag. Ditching k-map in favor of karnaugh-map seem to be a no-brainer for me, it's clearly inferior.

Comment: I notice that there are no questions with [tag:k-map] anymore. Have you edited to change old questions to the longer tag?

Comment: @Raphael, yes, I re-tagged them based on the suggestions here.  Your synonym proposal is a great idea.

Comment: @D.W. You may want to keep that in mind for future tag action. Creating the new tag, add the old one as synonym and then merging them (if appropriate) "retags" all questions without bumping them.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see a compelling reason to have a tag that covers Karnaugh maps but not, e.g., Quine-McCluskey or other methods for achieving the same goal.

If you want to follow that logic, we should just tag everything "computer science" and nuke all the other tags. There's nothing wrong with having a tag for the specific subject of Karnaugh maps, since people ask questions specifically about them.

But I agree that Karnaugh-map is vastly preferable to k-map.

Answer (score 1):

Since people have started using [karnaugh-map](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karnaugh-map), I have created a [synonym proposal](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/karnaugh-map/synonyms).

Comment: No voices against, so I'm mod-approving the synonym. (There are likely not enough users with sufficient tag-rep to upvote it.)